# Weird State Changes Updating with Overlay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm a little new to ReactJS and have found a weird bug with my code.  This is for www.drewpickering.com.  Please refer to that site.

I have some menu items at the bottom of the screen.  The hamburger menu button at the top right will trigger a slide to the menu items.  If you click that again, it should close the menu.

This works fine until I click on a menu item.  The menu item brings up an overlay that can be closed with an 'x' at the top right of the screen.  The problem occurs after I close a menu overlay.  After closing, click on the hamburger menu again and you'll see that the overlay appears instead of just closing the menu bar at the bottom of the screen.

I'm not sure if this is a css issue or the way I'm handling my state changes.

Here is the code starting with the Squares Menu Section:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import './squares-section.scss';
import Overlay from "../overlay/Overlay";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import $ from "jquery";

class SquaresSection extends Component {

    state = {
        showModal: false,
        modalType: "",
    }

    handleOverlay = (type) => {
        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        this.setState({
            showModal: true,
            modalType: type,
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <section id="squares-section">
                    <div className="square" onClick={this.handleOverlay.bind(this, "education")}><FontAwesomeIcon icon="user-graduate" size="2x" /></div>
                    <div className="square" onClick={this.handleOverlay.bind(this, "skills")}><FontAwesomeIcon icon="desktop" size="2x" /></div>
                    <div className="square" onClick={this.handleOverlay.bind(this, "experience")}><FontAwesomeIcon icon="building" size="2x" /></div>
                    <div className="square" onClick={this.handleOverlay.bind(this, "contact_me")}><FontAwesomeIcon icon="address-book" size="2x" /></div>
                    <div className="square" onClick={this.handleOverlay.bind(this, "volleyball")}><FontAwesomeIcon icon="volleyball-ball" size="2x" /></div>        
                </section>
                <Overlay show={this.state.showModal} type={this.state.modalType} hideTitle={this.modalType == 'volleyball' ? true : false} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default SquaresSection;
```

And here is the code for the Hamburger Icon Menu button:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './hamburgers.scss';

class Hamburgers extends Component {

    handleClick() {
        this.props.runFunction();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button id="hamburgers" type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        )
    }
}

export default Hamburgers;
```

I can provide css if needed. Thanks and I appreciate the help.

**UPDATED:**
Here is the code for this.props.runFunction():

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import IntroSection from '../introsection/IntroSection';
import scrollToElement from 'scroll-to-element';
import SquaresSection from "../squaressection/SquaresSection";
import './app-container.scss';
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faUserGraduate, faDesktop, faAward, faVolleyballBall, faAddressBook, faWindowClose, faBuilding } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'
import WebSiteBanner from "../websitebanner/WebSiteBanner";
import Hamburgers from '../hamburgers/Hamburgers';

library.add(
    faUserGraduate, 
    faDesktop, 
    faAward, 
    faVolleyballBall, 
    faAddressBook, 
    faWindowClose, 
    faBuilding
);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    console.log('*** Looks like we are in development mode! ***');
}

class AppContainer extends Component {

    state = {
        showMenu: false,
        showBanner: true,
    }

    toggleMenu() {
        this.setState({showMenu: !this.state.showMenu});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="main-content">
                    <Hamburgers runFunction={this.toggleMenu.bind(this)} />
                    <IntroSection showMenu={this.state.showMenu} />
                    <SquaresSection />
                </div>
                <WebSiteBanner />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AppContainer;
```

Hamburgers component next:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './hamburgers.scss';

class Hamburgers extends Component {

    handleClick() {
        this.props.runFunction();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button id="hamburgers" type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
                <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
                <span className="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        )
    }
}

export default Hamburgers;
```

And then here is the Overlay.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './overlay.scss';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import SkillsSection from "../skillssection/SkillsSection";
import EducationSection from "../educationsection/EducationSection";
import ContactMeSection from "../contactmesection/ContactMeSection";
import ExperienceSection from "../experiencesection/ExperienceSection";
import VolleyballSection from "../volleyballsection/VolleyballSection";

class Overlay extends Component {

    state = {
        show: false,
        type: "default",
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({ 
            show: nextProps.show, 
            type: nextProps.type,
            hideTitle: nextProps.type,
        });  
    }

    renderTypeComponent(type) {
        switch(type.toLowerCase()) {
            case "education":
                return <EducationSection />
            case "skills":
                return <SkillsSection />
            case "experience":
                return <ExperienceSection />
            case "contact_me":
                return <ContactMeSection />
            case "volleyball":
                return <VolleyballSection />                
            default:
                return <div>Default</div>
        }
    } 

    renderHeader(type) {
        let types = type.split("_");

        types.map((type, i) => {
            types[i] = type.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + type.substr(1);
        })      

        return types.join(" ");
    }

    closeOverlay() {
        // window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        this.setState({ show: false, type: '' });  
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <section id="overlay" style={{display: (this.state.show ? "block" : "none")}}>
                <div className="content">
                    <div className="overlay-close-box" onClick={this.closeOverlay.bind(this)}><FontAwesomeIcon icon="window-close" size="2x" /></div>
                    {this.renderTypeComponent(this.state.type)}
                </div>
                <div className="secret-overlay-close-box" onClick={this.closeOverlay.bind(this)}><FontAwesomeIcon icon="window-close" size="2x" /></div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}

export default Overlay;
```

Comment: You most likely have to structure your state so that you can set `showModal` to `false` and `modalType` to `""` when you press the `X`.

Comment: Can you please share the code for `this.prop.runFunction()`. That might be where the issue is.

Comment: I’ve posted the runFunction method above. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is when you click the 'X' you are only flipping `this.state.showModal` and the view will remember `this.state.modalType`. When you click the 'X' make sure to set `this.state.modalType` back to ""